# Storyboard From and To not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working? I want it to slide in from the left and slide in from the right. They both seem to be sliding from left and not starting from the very left or very right.

Before:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SlideInFromLeft" >
        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="500,0,-500,0" To="0" DecelerationRatio=".9" />
    </Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="SlideInFromRight">
    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0" To="-500,0,500,0" AccelerationRatio=".3"/>
</Storyboard>
```

After:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SlideInFromLeft" >
        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="1000,0,-1000,0" To="0" DecelerationRatio=".9" />
    </Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="SlideInFromRight">
    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0" To="-1000,0,1000,0" AccelerationRatio=".3"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

After messing with the from and to, I think I've figured it out. Take a look at the before and after.

Comment: You should be more specific about what the problem was and how you solved it, so other people who face the same problem will be able to solve it as well.